# Display Checked Checkbox in PDF converted from reportviewer

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

I am displaying Checkboxes in report viewer using this line:

```
=IIf( Fields!Field1.Value, Chr(254), Chr(168))
```

But when I convert it in PDF, the checkboxes that are `Checked` are not displaying in the PDF.

Did anyone solve it?

I use `Wingdings` font because other fonts are not supported for example Wingdings2 after install app.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a common problem and is being fixed in the next release.

Perhaps you could use √ (221A in Unicode Hex) as a workaround.

Source: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/431057/ssrs-2008-sp1-ctp-pdf-export-of-wingdings-characters-above-char-127-fails

Answer (score 0):

I am using this piece of code to render to PDF from RDLC.

```
var bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render(
            _reportRenderFormat, _deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
            out streamids, out warnings);
```

A sure way to get the checkboxes shown is to go to Placeholder properties in the textbox and select `HTML- Interpret HTML tags as styles`.

Then, for `checked` checkbox use this `Expression`:

```
="<font face=""Wingdings 2"" color=""green"">" & Chr(81) &"</font>" & "some other text"
```

For `unchecked` use this `expression`

```
="<font face=""Wingdings 2"" color=""red"">" & Chr(163) &"</font>" & "some other text"
```

[image: Palceholder properties]